# Rendering JSF/PrimeFaces components based on the number of rows returned by the PrimeFaces LazyDataModel<T>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to render some components based on the number of rows returned by the PrimeFaces `LazyDataModel<T>`.

For example, a `<p:panelGrid>` should be rendered only when there is at least one row is returned by the associated lazy data model.

```
<p:panelGrid rendered=#{bean.rowCount gt 0}>

    ...
    ...
    ...

</p:panelGrid>
```

Given below a `<p:dataList>` which is lazily loaded.

```
<p:dataList var="row"
            value="#{bean}"
            first="0"
            rows="10"
            paginator="true"
            lazy="true">

            ...
            ...
            ...

<p:dataList>
```

The bean is quite usual :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean extends LazyDataModel<Entity> implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private BeanService service;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<Entity> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
    {
        setRowCount(service.rowCount());
        return service.getList(first, pageSize);
    }    
}
```

The given `<p:panelGrid>` will not be rendered anymore because the lazy data model is unavailable, when the `rendered` attribute of `<p:panelGrid>` is processed.

The correct thing can happen, if the order of both `<p:panelGrid>` and `<p:dataList>` is interchanged but it is a design issue and cannot be thought of.

The given `<p:dataList>` holds a complex list of reporting data for preview (in combination with `<p:dataTable>`, `<p:panelGrid>` and some others) which is then exported to an MS-Excel workbook and the file is downloaded.

The list of reporting data (held by `<p:dataList>`) depends upon several (custom) filters composed of `<p:inputText>`, `<p:selectOneMenu>` etc. The list is AJAX updated based on the filter values/events.

The list can be empty at anytime depending upon the values of filters. In any case, if the `<p:dataList>` is empty, the `<p:panelGrid>` must not be rendered (`<p:panelGrid>` is just a simple example. There are other components too).

How can such components be rendered based on the number of rows returned by `LazyDataModel<T>` (ultimately from the associated database) without any extra overhead of executing extra JPA queries to count the number of rows which could be returned based on the values of filters (when there are already very complex/expensive reporting JPA criteria queries are being executed)?

Comment: You really need a datalist? The datalist do not handle p:ajax event. With some like a datatable you can use page event to update panel grid. Or at least you can put a remote command to update the panel when the page end all load

Comment: Yes I need a `<p:dataList>` in combination with `<p:dataTable>` and more components. This actually generates complex reports in a tabular format for users to preview which may then be downloaded to a Microsoft Excel file.

Comment: I think you can try with a remotecommand inside the list or datatable, If i've time i'll try and then post a reply

Answer (score 1):

As you set the row count in `load`, you might move

```
setRowCount(service.rowCount());
```

into a method executed prior to loading (or in the getter of row count as the last possibility), as I assume that `service.rowCount()` does not perform the loading itself, or am I wrong?

Comment: I want `service.rowCount()` to be executed only once in the `load()` method (which is most common). The method is actually parameterized, a `MultiValueMap<String, Object>` is passed as a parameter which holds filters. The business logic in the associated EJB is expensive and depends upon many filter conditions in generated SQL query. So, counting such rows from the database more than once on every filter event is not affordable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code issue is the way you defined the model. because of the Bean class you defined, the model row number will not be set unless it is called by the  `<p:dataList>`

the best thing I can offer is to have a bean and have the model inside it. something like this :

```
public class MainBean {
    private SERVICE service;
    private SEARCHOBJECT searchObject;

    private BaseListDataModel<LISTMODEL> dataModel = new BaseListDataModel<LM>() {
        @Override
        public List<LM> load(int first,
                             int pageSize,
                             String sortField,
                             SortOrder sortOrder,
                             Map<String, String> filters) {
            List<LM> result = new ArrayList<LM>();
            try {
                searchObject.setStartIndex(first);//this is used for my own business, you can handle the paging in some other way
                searchObject.setPageSize(pageSize);//this is used for my own business, you can handle the paging in some other way
                result = getService().search(searchObject);
                int rowCount = searchObject.getTotalRecordCount();
                this.setRowCount(rowCount);
            } catch (BusinessException ex) {
                log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                saveError(ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                saveError(new UnknownSystemException(ex));
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    ...
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An example with list and datatable.
There isn't ajax event for the table "change data". But when you do some filter, or sorting, or other refreshing only the table, you are doing that with ajax. So you can monitor ajax call and, when ajax call happen you can refresh your list.
Here the working code (trivial example):

*note that is not the command button to update the upper list, you can change the datatable with any another ajax command and still work*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<pe:head title="PrimeFaces Extensions - ShowCase">
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </f:facet>
</pe:head>
<f:view>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="pvis" >
            <p:dataList value="#{modelBean.data2}" var="d" rendered="#{ modelBean.data.size() > 0}" >
                #{d}|
            </p:dataList>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:remoteCommand name="updatelist" update="pvis" />
        <p:ajaxStatus onsuccess="updatelist();" />
        <p:dataTable value="#{modelBean.data}" var="d" id="table"  >
            <p:remoteCommand update="pvis" autoRun="true" immediate="true" />

            <p:column headerText="Value" >
                <p:outputLabel value="#{d}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton action="#{modelBean.addRandomData()}" update="table" value="Populate" />
    </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And the managed bean:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

        @Named
        @SessionScoped
        public class ModelBean implements Serializable {

            private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            private List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            public List<String> getData() {
                return data;
            }

            public void setData(List<String> data) {
                this.data = data;
            }

            public List<String> getData2() {
                return data2;
            }

            public void setData2(List<String> data2) {
                this.data2 = data2;
            }

            @PostConstruct
            public void init() {
                for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    data2.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
                }
            }

            public void addRandomData() {
                for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
                    Random random = new Random();
                    data.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
                }
            }
        }
```

Based on your comment:

> I  still do not find a way. Data tables are not suitable for reporting
>   when a list of reports are to be generated in a row

I add the following solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<pe:head title="PrimeFaces Extensions - ShowCase">
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </f:facet>
</pe:head>
<f:view>
    <h:form>

        <p:outputPanel deferred="true" deferredMode="load" >
            <p:panelGrid rendered="#{modelBean.rowCount > 0}" columns="1" >
                Show me only if Lazy Model has row
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:dataList  value="#{modelBean}" lazy="true" var="d" type="unordered" itemType="none" paginator="true" rows="10" styleClass="paginated" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                Base list
            </f:facet>
            #{d}
        </p:dataList>



    </h:form>
</f:view>
</html>
```

and the Lazy model:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ModelBean extends LazyDataModel<String> implements Serializable {

    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getData2() {
        return data2;
    }

    public void setData2(List<String> data2) {
        this.data2 = data2;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            data2.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
        }
    }

    /*public void addRandomData() {
        for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            data.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
        }
    }*/



    @Override
    public List<String> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0;i < pageSize;i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            data.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
        }

        setRowCount(100);
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        data = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0;i < pageSize;i++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            data.add("value:"+random.nextInt());
        }

        setRowCount(100);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Note the deferred load of the optional rendering (using output panel).

Another solution would be to run a remote command, to update the first panel at the end of the page.

**Note: to make visible a render *false*, you have to update the parent of that element**

Comment: I still do not find a way. Data tables are not suitable for reporting when a list of reports are to be generated in a row.

Comment: If i understund, I'll give an update with datalist and panel instead of datatable and datalist asap